# Aligned Equation Resizing? (Above or Below \textwidth)

Tags: math-mode, equations, margins, align, width

My input:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[t]
& \min\limits_{\bm{\Delta(P,Q),u}} & &  \sum\limits_i u_i, \\
& \text{s.t.} & &  (P_{min_k},Q_{min_k}) \leq (P_k,Q_k) \leq (P_{max_k},Q_{max_k}) \\
& & & -P_k\,C_k \leq Q_k \leq P_k\,C_k, \\
& & & -u_i \leq E_i +(\bm{K_{P,Q}\Delta(P,Q)})_i-\Omega_i\,\varepsilon\,\sqrt{\bm{K_{P,Q}^2\,\Delta(P,Q)^2}} - E_0, \\
& & & E_i +(\bm{K_{P,Q}\Delta(P,Q)})_i-\Omega_i\,\varepsilon\,\sqrt{\bm{K_{P,Q}^2\,\Delta(P,Q)^2}} - E_0 \leq u_i, \\
& & & i = 1,2,\dots,N_{LINES}.
\end{aligned}
\label{eq:ellip}
\end{equation}
```

Gives this output:
[image: output]

But the equation number should be on the first line, and it would be if the equations weren't too wide. The problem is, I can't resize the damn thing, as nothing works (resizebox, scalebox, etc.), as none of them works with `aligned` it seems.

Is there a way to get the equation number on the first line? I'm fine with the equation exceeding textwidth.

P.S. I really don't want to change my margins.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `align` environment from `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\min\limits_{\boldsymbol{\Delta(P,Q),u}} &  \sum\limits_i u_i, \\
\text{s.t.}\phantom{s.t.} &   (P_{\min_k},Q_{\min_k}) \leq (P_k,Q_k) \leq (P_{\max_k},Q_{\max_k})\nonumber \\
& -P_k\,C_k \leq Q_k \leq P_k\,C_k, \nonumber\\
& -u_i \leq E_i +(\boldsymbol{K_{P,Q}\Delta(P,Q)})_i-\Omega_i\,\varepsilon\,\sqrt{\boldsymbol{K_{P,Q}^2\,\Delta(P,Q)^2}} - E_0, \nonumber\\
& E_i +(\boldsymbol{K_{P,Q}\Delta(P,Q)})_i-\Omega_i\,\varepsilon\,\sqrt{\boldsymbol{K_{P,Q}^2\,\Delta(P,Q)^2}} - E_0 \leq u_i, \nonumber\\
& i = 1,2,\dots,N_{LINES}.\nonumber
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would use `flalign`  and the `\mathrlap/\mathclap` commands from `mathtools` (which loads `amsmath`), which  allows to group lines 3 and 4 of the conditions together:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
  & & \min_{\mathclap{\boldsymbol{\Delta(P,Q),u}}}\quad\sum_i u_i, & & & \\
  & \text{s.t.}\enspace \mathrlap{\begin{array}[t]{l}(P_{\min_k},Q_{\min_k}) \leq (P_k,Q_k) \leq (P_{\max_k},Q_{\max_k})\nonumber \\
    -P_k\,C_k \leq Q_k \leq P_k\,C_k, \nonumber\\
    -u_i \leq E_i +(\boldsymbol{K_{P,Q}\Delta(P,Q)})_i-\Omega_i\,\varepsilon\,\sqrt{\boldsymbol{K_{P,Q}^2\,\Delta(P,Q)^2}} - E_0 \leq u_i, \end{array}} & \\
  & \mathrlap{ i = 1,2,\dots,N_\mathrm{LINES}.}\nonumber
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]